# change height, width values based on variable in react-simple-image-slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am implementing an image slideshow kind of thing in react using npm package - react-simple-image-slider.

implementation->

```
export default function Home(){

const images = [
    { url: "images/1.jpg" },
    { url: "images/2.jpg" },
    { url: "images/3.jpg" },
  ];
const open = true;

    <SimpleImageSlider
                  width={`${open ? 896 : 880}`}
                  height={`${open ? 430 : 440}`}
                  images={images}
                  showBullets={true}
                  showNavs={true}
                />
}
```

i am trying to change height, width based on a variable. but this doesnt load anything. page is empty. am i missing something. please help.

Comment: Can you please share that full component where you are using this SimpleImageSlider. What does images prop/state contains. Please share some  more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try passing in numeric values directly and conditionally set them like follow code, I think it will work as expected.

```
<SimpleImageSlider
  width={open ? 896 : 880}
  height={open ? 430 : 440}
  images={images}
  showBullets={true}
  showNavs={true}
/>
```

Comment: i tried it but it wasnt working previously but i restarted vs code and voila it is working

Comment: Great to hear that it's working now